# Javascript remove spaces not working in IE8

Tags: javascript, spaces

I have a select list in my php file:

```
<select onchange="storePolishType(this.value,this.options[this.selectedIndex].text);" class="drop_down1">
<option value="10">BRP</option>           
<option value="10">Polished Ends</option>           
<option selected="selected" value="11">Sawed Ends</option>            
<option value="10">Steeled Ends</option>                    
</select>
```

I have a `storePolishType` function in a java script file. In that function I have tried to remove the spaces before and after the string:

```
function storePolishType(pTypeID,bottom_polish_name)
{
    if(typeof bottom_polish_name != 'undefined')
    {
        bottom_polish_name = bottom_polish_name.replace(/^\s\s*/, '').replace(/\s\s*$/, '');
    }
}
```

It is working fine in Firefox but not working in IE8. I have also tried `$.trim()` function of jquery, it is also not working in IE8.

Please help me to solve this problem.

Comment: Um..... works for me?  Don't see why you need two `\s` instead of just one, but otherwise there doesn't seem to be any problem.  How are you calling the function?

Comment: Would you please take another pass at formatting this readably? See the handy **How to Format** box to the right of the question text box, and [the page linked](http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help) from the **[?]** just above the question area. **Edit**: @bdares was kind enough to do it for you on this occasion.

Comment: Keep in mind that sometimes special characters are not recognized by javascript and throws error.

Comment: onchange of select list i have called the function storePolishType with selected value and text.

Comment: please help me to solve this issue.

Answer (score -1):

Try this:

```
function trim(s){
    if(typeof(s) === 'undefined'){return;}
    return s.replace(/^\s+|\s+$/g,"");
}
```

And if you want to use your function you can type " " instead of \s and try it.

Comment: I just tested it and it does not work. Obviously it works fine in Visual Studio 2015 but under IE8.